# Finding 3D camera location from a known 2D symbol inside an image

Tags: computer-vision, augmented-reality, pose-estimation

I'm beginning some research in 3D position finding using cameras.  I would like to try the technique where I take a picture of a known 2D symbol and work out camera position from the size, scale and skew of that symbol.  I know this technique is used in Augmented Reality to determine where the camera is and where to place the visual augmentations.  I have no experience in AR software, so I don't know what to call this technique (to search for info on it) and don't know if there are open source libraries I can use for getting camera location with this technique.

Alternately, are there any computer vision algorithms that can locate a repeatable location on a symbol so that I could identify 3+ points and do the math myself?

1. What is the terminology for these techniques that I can search for?
2. Are there existing open source packages that do this?

(If it matters, the symbols I would be using are irregularly shaped (not clean rectangles or squares like a QR code) and there will be plenty of unknown visual clutter around the symbol.  Imagine the symbol on a scrap of paper that is on top of a graffiti-covered wall.  The symbol will contrast from its immediate surroundings.)

Comment: Please don't down-vote this for not having researched the topic enough.  I want to do the research, but I don't currently know the terminology to use while searching.

Comment: "augmented reality" is a start. you also need to know "pose estimation". and you need 4 points. you need to be able to locate them precisely. usually it's a square. so the intersections of the edges are taken to be the corners. QR codes are not made for this and will not work, unless you want to write a master's thesis on this. irregular shapes are even worse. I can think of ways to approach this but not cheaply. if you can't pin your environment down, as you described that you can't, this will require an entire course of study for you to solve, def not calling a few APIs

Comment: this site is for programming questions. sometimes that's not just programming but actual problem solving, but it does contain programming. you should have posted pictures at least, if you can't present meaningful code. I hate to tap the signs but [ask], [mre] etc